# Table with text wrap and \textwidth width

Tags: tables, width, text

I'm trying to create a table which looks like this:

[image]

I can't seem to figure out how to wrap the text but also have the table itself the width=\textwidth. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at the `tabularx` package. For example as in `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}`. For the alternating row colors, you can use `\rowcolors` from the `xcolor` package (when loaded with the `table` option.)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

With reference to the remarks @leandriis this may help the OP to get  a head start

### The complete MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
 \rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{white}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
  \rowcolor{green!20}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{%
    Funktionale Anforderungen
                                              }\\
    Bezeichnung &Anforderung                    \\
    L00021-23-1 & Zuordnung zu Jobs              \\
                & Die Werkzeuge mussen fahig sein, Anwendungsfalle einem Job
                  zuzuordnen.    

    \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```